# android take pictures fast and filter by gps

Tags: android, image, camera, gps

beginner android programmer.

just before starting to make an app wanted to know how hard or even if possible to use the latest phone, e.g. samsung s7, to take 60 pics/second and mount phone in front of a moving vehicle and before storing each image check that it is not the same GPS location - that is not take pics when vehicle is stationary.

will the processor be able to handle the algorithm?

the other option is video recording but prefer still images with gps.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your phone is static... The only GPS location you can get is your phone's location...

Comment: like i said the phone is mounted in front of a moving vehicle